# How do I get MySQL Server to work on XAMPP on Windows 10?

Tags: mysql, xampp

Hi I have been trying for countless attempts to get the MYSQL server on XAMPP Control Panel to work without any success. I had the same problem with Apache however I rectified that by changing the port number. I have tried to change the port number in the `config>my.ini` file and `force_recover` addition however I have literally hit a stumbling block.

**# The MySQL server**

```
[mysqld] port= 3307 socket = "C:/xampp/mysql/mysql.sock" basedir = "C:/xampp/mysql"  tmpdir = "C:/xampp/tmp"  datadir = "C:/xampp/mysql/data" pid_file = "mysql.pid"
    # enable-named-pipe key_buffer = 16M max_allowed_packet = 1M sort_buffer_size = 512K net_buffer_length = 8K read_buffer_size = 256K read_rnd_buffer_size = 512K myisam_sort_buffer_size = 8M log_error = "mysql_error.log"
```

I have retrospectively changed all port numbers to match what I had changed but still nothing it just keeps failing and asking to debug. Any ideas of what else I can do to get this to work on XAMPP? I desperately need to get this working to continue with a project which is long overdue.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Could be a matter of insufficient rights. Can you post what it says in the log?
-Melle

Comment: Hi Melle thanks for getting back to me this is what it says in the log -

Comment: 2015-11-10 15:26:56 10fc InnoDB: Warning: Using innodb_additional_mem_pool_size is DEPRECATED. This option may be removed in future releases, together with the option innodb_use_sys_malloc and with the InnoDB's internal memory allocator.
2015-11-10 15:26:56 4348 [Note] InnoDB: Using mutexes to ref count buffer pool pages
2015-11-10 15:26:56 4348 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled

Comment: 2015-11-10 15:26:56 4348 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
2015-11-10 15:26:56 4348 [Note] InnoDB: Not using CPU crc32 instructions
2015-11-10 15:26:56 4348 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 16.0M
2015-11-10 15:26:56 4348 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2015-11-10 15:26:56 4348 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2015-11-10 15:26:57 4348 [Note] InnoDB: 128 rollback segment(s) are active.
2015-11-10 15:26:57 4348 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start

Comment: 2015-11-10 15:26:57 4348 [Note] InnoDB: 128 rollback segment(s) are active.
2015-11-10 15:26:57 4348 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2015-11-10 15:26:57 4348 [Note] InnoDB:  Percona XtraDB (http://www.percona.com) 5.6.26-74.0 started; log sequence number 1835027
2015-11-10 15:26:57 6140 [Note] InnoDB: Dumping buffer pool(s) not yet started
2015-11-10 15:26:57 4348 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.

Comment: 2015-11-10 15:26:57 4348 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
2015-11-10 15:26:57 4348 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
2015-11-10 15:26:57 4348 [Note] C:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysqld.exe: ready for connections.
Version: '10.1.8-MariaDB'  socket: ''  port: 3306  mariadb.org binary distribution
2015-11-10 15:27:11 5152 [Note] C:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysqld.exe: Normal shutdown

Comment: I tried installing WAMP Server as well as I desperately need MySQL server but nothing happens when I try to launch it despite it saying the installation was a success and showing on my programs list